# jQuery addClass() not working in IE (8, 9 and probably the other one too)

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Simple html:

```
<div class="stuff-choice">
  <div class="item a">
    <label class="signup-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="a" name="stuff[a][]" id="stuff_choice_" class="things">
      <strong>A</strong>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically I detect when someone click on the checkbox with the css class `.things`, and then I updated the parent `<div>` with a css class `.selected`.

The JS: (with a `$(document).ready(function(){` ...

```
$('.things').click(function() {     
    item = $(this).closest("div");
    if ($(this).attr('checked') != null)
        $(item).addClass('selected');
    else
        $(item).removeClass('selected');
});
```

This works like a charm under:
- Safari (mac & win)
- Firefox (mac & win)

But not under IE !?!?

I have no clue why...

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 4):

IE is notorious for freaking out if you don't declare your variables by prefixing them with "var".

So try this:

```
var item = $(this).closest("div");
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue :) Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Try this, `closest` already gives a jQuery object you dont have to wrap it in `$()` and also `is()` method can be used to check is checked or not.

```
$('.things').click(function() {     
    $item = $(this).closest("div");
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        $item.addClass('selected');
    else
        $item.removeClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: I fixed the item wrapper issue in my post, but this guy refactored the whole thing to be more efficient. Use this guy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're issue is the object you're calling `.addClass` on.

```
item = $(this).closest("div");
```

In this line, `item` is set to a jQuery object.

Therefore, in your next statement, you don't need the `$(item)` syntax, just use `item`.

```
$('.things').click(function() {     
    item = $(this).closest("div");
    if ($(this).attr('checked') != null)
        item.addClass('selected');
    else
        item.removeClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used .prop('disabled', 'disabled') instead of addClass('hide') - it worked for me.